# How to update properties of a file just created by Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a flow that is triggered on File Modified and there is a Condition that looks for the Field ACTION to be updated to SPLIT. If this is true, then the automation looks at a Choice field (multiselect) and creates a new file for every selection in the Choice field. It also appends the file name with that choice so that there will be unique file names. Once this is complete, I would like the ACTION field to be cleared on these new copied files and the Choice field to only contain the Choice that is now in the file name. Finally, delete the original file. I am getting some results correct like the file name, but the ACTION field isn't clearing and the Choice field still contains all choices. Does someone have a suggestion?
[image]

[image]